# Importing custom attributes using Magmi

Tags: magento, magmi

I'm currently trying to use Magmi to update around 1000 products in Magento based on their SKU. Here is an example of my CSV file:

```
"store","mpn","sku","cat_brand"
"admin","TA50 WR","AA0096","Aria"
```

I have two custom attributes called mpn / cat_brand that are currently empty on all of the products. 
My question is can you update custom attributes using Magmi?

Also, is there a way to filter the SKU; in Magento the SKU's seem to be being appended with a number, so they end up looking like this: AA0096:1002. Is there a way to use a regular expression on the SKU? or do you think Magmi will still match them up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course, magmi can update any attribute based on its code in the header (either user custom or standard magento)

for skus, you need to use the exact magento sku. so have a line per magento sku for updating values.

magento is not "appending" anything to sku by default, in fact i suppose you have "configurable" product with root skus (AA0096) & associates simple items (AA0096:xxxx) , each being a separate reference.

Magmi has no "multiple match" mode for one item line in the csv, it would be handy but also dangerous. so you'll have to have one line per final sku in magento to have magmi update each wanted sku.